# How to use Multiprocessing with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to use multiprocessing using selenium in python. My code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from multiprocessing import Pool
import xlwings as xw

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://example.com")

wb = xw.Book('my_file.xlsm')
sht = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]
final_list = []

search = driver.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtByName")
for item in search:
       z = item.find_element_by_class_name("valuetext")
       info = z.find_element_by_tag_name("span")
       final_list.append(info.text)

def automate(num):
    col = num
    list_item = final_list[num]   
    sht.range(1, col).value = each


if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = Pool(processes=4)
    data = p.map(automate,range(1,20))
```

The issue I'm having is for each of the 4 processes the web page is re-opened again and I don't understand why. If `p.map` is only targeting the `automate` function then why is  the rest of the code run for every process?

I'm still new to multiprocessing so am not sure if that's just how it works.Is there another way to do this to ensure the processes only target the function itself, or is there a way I could use threading?

Comment: all of the code that is not inside a function will get executed when you run the script.

Comment: also, you don't want to share an instance of the driver with each process.  I'd suggest starting with a framework that supports parallelism rather than rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

In the examples in the [multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), they suggest using `Pool` with a context manager, i.e.,

`with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    print(pool.map(f, range(10))`

The's the most stand-out different I immediately see between your use and the docs. I don't see it spelled out, but I would infer based on your observation, that the framework is "reimporting" (so to speak) your module in each process that it spawned, and that's resulting in the behavior you report: namely, multiple browsers opening.

To prevent that, I would recommend putting the initialization code within a function; if you want to share the `final_list`, you should probably do so with a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) or other data structure supported by `multiprocess`.

Comment: Yeh even using `with` has the same effect. I'll see if I get around it by wrapping it in functions